# VIM Code completion anywhere in the string

Tags: vim

By default code completion in VIM searches from the start of the word. Is it possible to make it anywhere in the word. For example, if I have "MY_DEVICE_CTRL_ADR" and "MY_DEVICE_STAT_ADR" in the C header file, can i start typing CTRL_ and then have VIM complete it for me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to type `CTRL_` and be offered all the words in the current file which contain that string? This could be achieved using custom completion, but I suspect the results might be unwieldy. If this is a single ad hoc case you might be better off using abreviations (`help :ab`).

Comment: Yes, with CTRL_ it should display all the defines in header file which contains CTRL_ anywhere in the string. Right now, vim tries to match string which starts with CTRL_ and not MY_DEVICE_CTRL_ADR.

Comment: Paul, I'm With @PrinceGoulash here, abbreviations might be a better solution to this than completing. However, interesting problem!

Comment: abbreviations won't help in this case. The header file has few hundred macros defined and it is impossible to create abbreviations for all of them. This is a typical code completion scenario, but I was the search to match anywhere in the string rather than from the start of the string. Even a regex solution is good enough. Is it possible to have regex in code completion?

Comment: @Paul: It is possible to have a custom completion function which does a simple regex grep on a given file and returns all the results as completion suggestions. Although I'm not sure how this would interact with other plugins (e.g. ctags, etc).

Comment: It looks like some kind of fuzzy matching for code completion. Out of curiosity, do you know of an IDE/editor providing this feature? I've never seen such a thing anywhere.

Comment: @PrinceGoulash: Thanks, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @romainl: I don't know of any other IDE/editor. But i think this is a nice to have feature where the list of functions and macros are too long :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this is very rough-and-ready, but it appears to work (at least in simple cases).

First of all here is a function which performs a vimgrep on a given a file. This needs to be a separate function so it can be called silently later on.

```
function! File_Grep( leader, file )
    try
        exe "vimgrep /" . a:leader . "/j " . a:file
    catch /.*/
        echo "no matches"
    endtry
endfunction
```

Now here is a custom-completion function which calls `File_Grep()` and returns a list of matching words. The key is the call  to the `add()` function, which appends a match to the list if search term (`a:base`) appears ANYWHERE in the string. (See `help complete-functions` for the structure of this function.)

```
function! Fuzzy_Completion( findstart, base )
    if a:findstart
        " find start of completion
        let line = getline('.')
        let start = col('.') - 1
        while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\w'
            let start -= 1
        endwhile
        return start
    else
        " search for a:base in current file
        let fname = expand("%")
        silent call File_Grep( a:base, fname )
        let matches = []
        for this in getqflist()
            call add(matches, matchstr(this.text,"\\w*" . a:base . "\\w*"))
        endfor
        call setqflist([])
        return matches
    endif
endfunction
```

Then you just need to tell Vim to use the complete function:

```
set completefunc=Fuzzy_Completion
```

and you can use `<c-x><x-u>` to invoke the completion. Of course, the function could be used to search any file, rather than the current file (just modify the `let fname` line).

Even if this isn't the answer you were looking for, I hope it aids you in your quest!

Comment: Wanted to test it… and was on a [Scratch] buffer (no file name…) of course `vimgrep` fails in this case. For the rest it is very nice.

Comment: If you have all the header files in a folder and want to search, replace fname as below:    let fname = "path_to_folder/include/**.h"